# qgis2web basemaps sit on top of all other layers in Leaflet and OpenLayers on webpages

Tags: qgis-3, qgis2web, qgis-openlayers-plugin, leaflet-plugins

[image]

Generating a webpage from a map always elevates the basemap from the bottom (within the QGIS Project) to the top (on the webpage map). This means the additional layers can never be overlaid to fully see the map.

Can anyone help?

[image]

No matter what I do, I cannot get the basemap to sit at the bottom of the webpage layers.

Comment: What kind of layer is the Stamen Terrain?

Comment: Basemaps from QuickMapServices or from XYZ Tiles produce the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/935
The problem was answered by jukos here.
Its a matter of ensuring no layers are contained within groups within the QGIS desktop project.